# Is it safe for backward compatibility to make abstract method non abstract with empty implementation

Tags: java

Let's suppose we have such class:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass{

  protected abstract void validate() throws ValidationException;

  public void doAction() throws ValidationException{
    validate();
    //some more actions
  }
}
```

This class has a lot of implementations. And I see that in 90% of implementations method **validate()** does not have a body, i.e. it is empty in 90% of inheritors. I want to refactor it to:

```
protected void validate() throws ValidationException{
   //empty body
}
```

Is this refactoring is backward comptible?

Comment: Yes, it is backward compatible.

Comment: "*This class has a lot of implementations. And I see that in 90% of implementations method validate() does not have a body, i.e. it is empty in 90% of inheritors.*" - Why is that? This is a design smell. --- "*Is this refactoring is backward comptible?*" - What is the gain? Is the method no longer used? If so, remove it from the interface.

Comment: Time to look for new design imho.

Comment: I'd say it's more or less backwards compatible. There could be someone using some kind of reflection that expect `validate` to be abstract. It would be a major version bump imho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In technical "will it work?" terms, it's fine. The only real concern that immediately comes to mind is a longer-term maintenance concern: If at some point it gets code added to it, many of the implementations probably won't call it because used to be abstract (e.g., they won't have `super.validate()`), so they'll miss out running that (hypothetical) code.

The other vague concern is that it means that subclass authors don't necessarily have to stop and think "Do I need to do something in `validate`?" Whereas with your current structure, they are at least prompted to think about that.

Answer (score 2):

Well yes. In the old version you've forced to implement it, now every implementation would just be overriding it.

Nothing (well, you could have some really funky code, but that's unlikely) will break as the only special handling of an abstract method is to force implementing it.

Comment: The actual question is: What is the gain by providing an empty "default" implementation? If the method is not used, it should be removed from the interface.

Comment: There are plenty of times where a method is unimplemented in 90% cases, that doesn't mean it's not used.